# change ANSI to UTF-8 in sql

Tags: sql-server, utf-8, ansi

I am trying to export  data from excel sheet into sql server.There are some arablic field,am getting arabic value as "????" in my DB. Datatype for the column is nvarchar.Please Help

Comment: how are you exporting data? Copy and paste? SSIS? If the latter, what's your method of connecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do something like this

use arabic collation or use unicode(nvarchar(max))

```
CREATE TABLE #t11
    (

    column1 NVARCHAR(100) 

    )
    INSERT INTO #t11 VALUES(N'لا أتكلم العربية')

    SELECT * FROM #t11
```

## [fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/57287/1)

Comment: HO HO HO... happy 2 help !!

Comment: I have found one more solution...select collation as arabic during DB Creation,which may help to avoid this issue